# Elasticsearch aggregations query for multiselection

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following problem: In my Application, I have multiple multi-select-comboboxes for filtering search results.
[image]

the comboboxes show facets of the search results:
[image]

Depending of selections in a filter, the facet results decrease in the other filters. So far, so good. However, the results also degrease for the other possible selections in the combobox:

[image]

here, I would need the facets WITHOUT the already selected results. In this particulair field.

The query I use so far looks like that:

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "depictionID"
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "cave.caveTypeID": [
                        4
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "cave.siteID": [
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "cave.districtID": [
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "cave.regionID": [
                        1
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "CaveType": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "cave.caveTypeID"
        }
    },
    "Region": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "cave.regionID"
        }
    },
    "Site": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "cave.siteID"
        }
    },
    "District": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "cave.districtID"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I figured so far, that I need to put the selected fields out of the query and filter for them in the aggregation-section. However, I do not understand, how that could work, when two or more comboboxes have already selections.

Has anybody a good Idea, how to solve that problem?

Sincerely,

Erik

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/filter-search-results.html) instead, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "depictionID"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "cave.caveTypeID": [
              4
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "cave.siteID": [
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "cave.districtID": [
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "cave.regionID": [
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "CaveType": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cave.caveTypeID"
      }
    },
    "Region": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cave.regionID"
      }
    },
    "Site": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cave.siteID"
      }
    },
    "District": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cave.districtID"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Yet, as far as I understand, than thay are not interdependent any more?

Comment: Yes, `post_filter` runs after aggregations, said differently, aggregations are not affected by `post_filter`

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer. I am not sure, if one can solve it more "elegant"

Comment: thanks for the help, by the way, it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure why post_filter didn't do the job for you, but glad you figured out

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did solve the problem by shifting the filters into the aggregation part, however, I had to make a aggregation for every single combobox as every combobox needs an aggregation WITHOUT its own filter, thus the aggregations grew dramaticly:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "caveType": {
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "cave.districtID": [
                    4
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "site": {
                "filter": {
                    "terms": {
                        "cave.siteID": [
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "caveType": {
                        "terms": {
                            "size": 10000,
                            "field": "cave.caveTypeID"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "site": {
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "cave.districtID": [
                    4
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "caveType": {
                "filter": {
                    "terms": {
                        "cave.caveTypeID": [
                            4
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "site": {
                        "terms": {
                            "size": 10000,
                            "field": "cave.siteID"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "district": {
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "cave.siteID": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "caveType": {
                "filter": {
                    "terms": {
                        "cave.caveTypeID": [
                            4
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "district": {
                        "terms": {
                            "size": 10000,
                            "field": "cave.districtID"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "region": {
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "cave.districtID": [
                    4
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "site": {
                "filter": {
                    "terms": {
                        "cave.siteID": [
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "caveType": {
                        "filter": {
                            "terms": {
                                "cave.caveTypeID": [
                                    4
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "region": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "size": 10000,
                                    "field": "cave.regionID"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"size": 0
```

}

If anyone has a more "elegant" way to do that, be my guest.